# Xcode 13.3 Build Failed because of Cycle in Dependencies between targets libsignal-protocol-swift

Tags: swift, xcode13.3

After updating to Xcode 13.3 facing Build failed issues with `libsignal-protocol-swift` library.

This is happening while building second time while after cleaning and building for first time it is working fine. Also, Xcode 13.2.1 has no such errors.

Xcode Error as below :

Cycle inside libsignal-protocol-swift iOS; building could produce unreliable results. This usually can be resolved by moving the target's Headers build phase before Compile Sources.

```
Cycle details:
→ Target 'libsignal-protocol-swift iOS' has link command with output '/Users/ankitkhanna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueSecures-brawgzawheasvqbvhxxglfnlvdlw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SignalProtocol.framework/SignalProtocol'
○ Target 'libsignal-protocol-swift iOS' has compile command for Swift source files
○ Target 'libsignal-protocol-swift iOS' has copy command from '/Users/ankitkhanna/Documents/Project-Files/Desk-Factors-Project-Files/BlueChats-IOS-master/libsignal-protocol-swift-master/libsignal-protocol-swift/SignalProtocol.h' to '/Users/ankitkhanna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueSecures-brawgzawheasvqbvhxxglfnlvdlw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SignalProtocol.framework/Headers/SignalProtocol.h'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After struggling for sometime the solution was actually the same as mentioned in Xcode suggestions.

i.e. to Move the Headers in project Target -> Build Phases on top Compiled sources.

Drag and move Headers above Compile Sources fixed the error.
Please see the image for reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my case, after applying this method and upgrading to Xcode 14, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 4):

I've faced the same issue after updating to Xcode 13.3; however, in my case, I didn't have Headers in Build Phases.

I've followed these steps to solve it:

1. **Precondition**: Xcode must be closed.
2. Delete the `DerivedData` folder:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

3. In the Terminal, type the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCBuild EnableSwiftBuildSystemIntegration 1
```

Comment: u are tend to using legacy build system, that deprecated from old XCode

Answer (score 1):

The answer that is marked as a solution didn't work for me. I moved the section on the top, tried to reinstall pods and removed `TodayExtension`, as another person suggested in another thread. Nothing helped. But that project was cloned from Github before update to Sonoma and Xcode 15. So, I deleted the project with Github desktop client, and then cloned in again (but to another folder). After that I had the same error, but when I tried again to move the section in Build Phases at the top of the list - it worked! So, the marked solution actually works, but maybe you have to reclone your project before (if possible).