# Cycle in dependencies between targets 'Unity-iPhone' and 'UnityFramework'; building could produce unreliable results

Tags: xcode

*Cycle in dependencies between targets 'Unity-iPhone' and 'UnityFramework'; building could produce unreliable results. This usually can be resolved by moving the target's Headers build phase before Compile Sources.
Cycle path: Unity-iPhone → UnityFramework → Unity-iPhone*

Received with M1 Mac, while trying to build to device from Xcode 13.3

Comment: You might find this post in the unity forums insightful: https://forum.unity.com/threads/xcode-version-13-3-13e113-error-cycle-in-dependencies.1268720/

Comment: In my case, upgrading to Xcode 14 resolved the issue. If you are not using Xcode 14, try upgrading Xcode.

Answer (score 8):

To solve the issue, on Xcode, you need to go to Build Phases -> UnityFramework, and make sure the Headers is listed above the Compile Sources.

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Changing build order in Xcode from 'Manual order' to 'Dependency order' may help.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Running in Terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCBuild EnableSwiftBuildSystemIntegration 1
```

To enable the new build system solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Move Headers above Compile Sources fixed the error. Please see the image for reference. I have referenced the following [Xcode 13.3 Build Failed because of Cycle in Dependencies between targets libsignal-protocol-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71732410/xcode-13-3-build-failed-because-of-cycle-in-dependencies-between-targets-libsign)

[image]

Comment: Im using XCode 14 then does not have Header

Comment: I am using Xcode 15(it does not have Header too) and facing this error suddenly, my project was building with Xcode 14.3. With Sonoma and Xcode 15 I am facing this issue.
Do you how to fix for Xcode 15?